ion-picker does not display columns in ionic 7.2.0
I'm using ion-picker in my ionic v7.2.0 project but it doesn't show the columns, only an empty gray rectangle is shown in my page, so I guess it's not consuming the columns of my ts.
I have already visited the official ionic documentation and copied the test examples for angular, but still the picker does not show the options.
<ion-picker
  [isOpen]="isPickerOpen"
  [columns]="pickerColumns"
  [buttons]="pickerButtons"
  (didDismiss)="setOpen(false)">
</ion-picker>

My page:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  isPickerOpen = false;

  public pickerColumns = [
    {
      name: 'col1',
      options: [
        { text: 'Opción 1', value: '1' },
        { text: 'Opción 2', value: '2' },
        { text: 'Opción 3', value: '3' }
      ]
    }
  ];

  public pickerButtons = [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel',
    },
    {
      text: 'Confirm',
      handler: (value: any) => {
        console.log('Selected value:', value);
        // Verificar la estructura exacta del valor
      },
    },
  ];

  setOpen(isOpen: boolean) {
    this.isPickerOpen = isOpen;
  }
}

someone who can help me please
